# Ubuntu SDK - Example clocks wont run in emulator

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, ubuntu-emulator

I'm trying to start the example "clocks" from the ubuntu SDK in the phone emulator. After adding the emulated device, booting it and pressing play nothing happens.

How can I found out what is going wrong? Maybe it would be helpful if someone can tell his way?

Answer (score 0):

You are using an example from Qt. It doesn't include packaging config files to install it on the device/emulator.

Create another project with New Project > Ubuntu > QML App with Simple UI (qmlproject), Framework ubuntu-sdk-14.10-qml.

Copy 'content', 'doc' and 'clocks.qml' from the "clocks" example to this new project.

Rename clocks.qml to Clocks.qml.

Add that widget into Main.qml by inserting 'Clocks{}' into code somewhere among Labels and Buttons.

It should work. Watch 'Compile Output' for compile and packaging errors, 'Application Output' for install and runtime errors.